# Show view when pin pressed crashed

Tags: objective-c, button, dictionary, annotations, mkmapview

I have a code that shows a pin on MKMapView and have a button, and I want that when the button is pressed it switches to another view like in the apple maps. 
I read some tutorials and answers here but every time I press the button the app crashes.
The crash log is "libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException". This is my code:

ThirdViewController.h (mapviewcontroller):

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>




@interface ThirdViewController : UIViewController <MKMapViewDelegate>

@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *userLatitude;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *userLongitude;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet MKMapView *mapview;



@end
```

ThirdViewController.m (mapviewcontroller):

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    mapview.delegate = self;
    mapview.showsUserLocation = YES;

     UILongPressGestureRecognizer *longPressGesture = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer     alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleLongPressGesture:)];
    [self.mapview addGestureRecognizer:longPressGesture];
    [longPressGesture release];

    //Span
    MKCoordinateSpan span;
    span.latitudeDelta = THE_SPAN;
    span.longitudeDelta = THE_SPAN;


    //Annotation
    NSMutableArray * locations = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    CLLocationCoordinate2D location;
    AdressAnnotation *myann;



    //Annotation
    myann = [[AdressAnnotation alloc]init];
    location.latitude = LOCATION_LATITUDE;
    location.longitude = LOCATION_LONGITUDE;
    myann.coordinate = location;
    myann.title = @"Text";
    myann.subtitle = @"Text";
    [locations addObject:myann];



    [self.mapview addAnnotations:locations];



}



- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView annotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view     calloutAccessoryControlTapped:(UIControl *)control
{

    if ([(UIButton*)control buttonType] == UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure){
        PlaceViewController *detailView=[[PlaceViewController alloc]     initWithNibName:@"detailView" bundle:nil];
        [[self navigationController] pushViewController:detailView animated:YES];
        [detailView release];


    }

}

- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id     <MKAnnotation>)annotation
{


    MKPinAnnotationView *pinView = nil;
    if(annotation!= mapview.userLocation)
    {
        static NSString *defaultPin = @"pinIdentifier";
        pinView = (MKPinAnnotationView*)[mapview     dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:defaultPin];
        if(pinView == nil)
            pinView = [[[MKPinAnnotationView alloc]initWithAnnotation:annotation     reuseIdentifier:defaultPin]autorelease];
        pinView.pinColor = MKPinAnnotationColorRed; //Optional
        pinView.canShowCallout = YES; // Optional
        pinView.animatesDrop = YES;
        pinView.draggable = YES;

        pinView.canShowCallout = YES;

        // Add a detail disclosure button to the callout.
        UIButton* rightButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];
        pinView.rightCalloutAccessoryView = rightButton;
    }
    else
    {
        [mapview.userLocation setTitle:@"You are Here!"];
    }
    return pinView;
}

- (void)dealloc {
    [mapview release];
    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

Comment: What is the crash log?

Comment: libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

Comment: Add an exception breakpoint, search SO to find out how to do that. Run your app and when it gets the exception press continue a couple of times and you will get a good crash log. Add it to your question.

Comment: @Euroboy Exception crashes without an exception breakpoint generally do not have a useful crash log.

Comment: I think I found it: 0x197969d3c, 0x18e9280e8, 0x197f53aa0

Comment: we don't understand the underlying pointers to the objects that you have put in your comment

Comment: At least you could add NSLogs everywhere to help you figure out or narrow down to the exact line where it crashes.  Learn to do some basic debugging in Xcode.  Besides exception breakpoints, you can also add your own so you can step through the code line by line.  In calloutAccessoryControlTapped, you are doing a pushVC.  Do you actually have a navigation controller in your app?

Comment: The code was for XIB file but I used a storyboard, so I changed the code